# Shouldn't the input logic apply to all input elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing some logic to handle the behavior of input elements when a user focuses in on it, then clicks out of it and tries to submit without typing anything out in the input. An error should be the result. Now when the user focuses back into the input field, the error should remain until the uses starts typing something in the input, anything.

Now that is still a work in progress, but what I don't understand or what my expectation was, that I could write this logic out once and it would apply to all input elements, but it doesn't, it seems to just apply it to the first input element. Do I need to copy and paste the logic more than once per element?

I am already violating DRY principles all over the place. Why is this logic not applying to all input elements?

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
  if (e.target.value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
    document.querySelector('.animated-label').classList.add('error');
    document.querySelector('.error-block').style.display = "block";
  }
});

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
  if (!e.target.value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
    document.querySelector('.animated-label').classList.remove('error');
    document.querySelector('.animated-label').classList.add('focus');
    document.querySelector('.error-block').style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.rds-form .animated-label {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #767676;
  display: block;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.rds-form .animated-label.focus {
  border: 2px solid #8b0;
  outline: thin dotted black;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.rds-form .animated-label.required.field label:after {
  background-color: #8b0;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  right: -0.5em;
  top: -0.5em;
  width: 5px;
}

.rds-form .field.animated-label.required.error label:after {
  background-color: #cc2233;
}

.rds-form .field-group.error-group .error-block {
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.rds-form .field-group.error-group .error-block .help-block {
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<form class="rds-form">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="field animated-label text required">
        <label class="control-label" for="oldPassword">Current password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="oldPassword" aria-required="true" autocomplete="on" style="max-height: 67px; padding-top: 27px;" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="error-current-password">
        <div class="error-block" style="display: none;">
          <p class="help-block error" id="error-current-password">This is where the error should be.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="field animated-label text required">
        <label class="control-label" for="NewPassword_NewPassword">New password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="NewPassword.NewPassword" id="NewPassword" aria-required="true" autocomplete="on" style="max-height: 67px; padding-top: 27px;" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="error-current-password">
        <div class="error-block" style="display: none;">
          <p class="help-block error" id="error-current-password">This is where the error should be.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So the behavior you are seeing in the first input element, I want it to be the same behavior for all input elements in the form I create.

I tried iterating through the `input` elements but I am not getting the functionality I was before:

```
const inputBlurs = document.querySelectorAll('input').addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
  for (const i = 0, inputBlur; inputBlur = inputBlurs[i++];) {
    if (e.target.value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.animated-label').classList.add('error');
    document.querySelectorAll('.error-block').style.display = "block";
  }
}
});

const inputClicks = document.querySelectorAll('input').addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
  for (const i = 0, inputClick; inputClick = inputClicks[i++];) {
    if (!e.target.value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.animated-label').classList.remove('error');
    document.querySelectorAll('.animated-label').classList.add('focus');
    document.querySelectorAll('.error-block').style.display = "none";
  }
}
});
```

With the below implementation, I am still only getting one input element reacting to the focus and blur:

```
const errorHandler = e => {
  const eTarg = e.target;
  console.log(eTarg.tagName, e.type)
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (const i = 0; i < inputs.length; inputs++) {
    if (eTarg.tagName === "INPUT" && eTarg.value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
      if (e.type === "blur") {
        document.querySelector('.animated-label').classList.add('error');
        document.querySelector('.error-block').style.display = "block";
      } else if (e.type==="focus") {
        document.querySelector('.animated-label').classList.remove('error');
        document.querySelector('.animated-label').classList.add('focus');
        document.querySelector('.error-block').style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }  
};
const transmit = e => alert(e.target)

document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('focus', errorHandler, true); // NOTE the true
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('blur', errorHandler, true)
```

Comment: Because you are only adding the event listener to the first input element.  `querySelector` returns just one element.

Comment: If you want the logic on all the inputs, you will have to use `querySelectorAll`, loop over them, and put the event listener on all of them.  Or, change up the logic to be in a delegate form.

Comment: Hmm, I would still be duplicating code it seems, which is not a priority right now whether I am or not, but from what you shared, I would have to do a `for` loop to handle `blur` and then another `for` loop to handle `focus`.

Comment: If the concern is duplicating code, then either use a delegate form of event listening, or extract those anonymous functions out to named functions, and reuse them for your binding loops.

Comment: @Taplar, can you review what I added in OP? I just tried to iterate over the `input` elements, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: You're looping in the wrong part.  `[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(input => ...stuff... )` or `var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input'); for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ...`

Comment: `querySelectorAll` does not have `addEventListener` and the error message in your console should say that. You need to loop over the HTML collection and bind the event to each element

Comment: @Taplar, I implemented the above with a `for` loop but the behavior is still only applying to one input element.

Comment: Your loop makes no sense though. You are looping over the return value of `addEventListener` (in an absolutely strange way too) and not over the elements in the node list that `querySelectorAll` returns.

Comment: @CherryDT, yes I realized that afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate to the nearest common container

**Note** focus and blur need the event capturing boolean set to true

```js
const errHandler = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  console.log(tgt.tagName, tgt.name, e.type)
  if (tgt.tagName === "INPUT" && tgt.value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
    const parent = tgt.closest(".animated-label");
    const err = parent.querySelector('.error-block');
    if (e.type === "blur") {
      parent.classList.add('error');
      err.querySelector("p.error").textContent = "Please fill "+tgt.name
      err.style.display = "block";
    } else if (e.type==="focus") {
      parent.classList.remove('error');
      parent.classList.add('focus');
      err.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('focus', errHandler, true); // NOTE the true
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('blur', errHandler, true)
```

```css
.rds-form .animated-label {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #767676;
  display: block;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.rds-form .animated-label.focus {
  border: 2px solid #8b0;
  outline: thin dotted black;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.rds-form .animated-label.required.field label:after {
  background-color: #8b0;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  right: -0.5em;
  top: -0.5em;
  width: 5px;
}

.rds-form .field.animated-label.required.error label:after {
  background-color: #cc2233;
}

.rds-form .field-group.error-group .error-block {
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.rds-form .field-group.error-group .error-block .help-block {
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<form class="rds-form" id="myForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="field animated-label text required">
        <label class="control-label" for="oldPassword">Current password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" aria-required="true" autocomplete="on" style="max-height: 67px; padding-top: 27px;" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="error-current-password">
        <div class="error-block" style="display: none;">
          <p class="help-block error" id="error-current-password">This is where the error should be.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field animated-label text required">
        <label class="control-label" for="NewPassword_NewPassword">New password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="NewPassword.NewPassword" id="NewPassword" aria-required="true" autocomplete="on" style="max-height: 67px; padding-top: 27px;" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="error-current-password">
        <div class="error-block" style="display: none;">
          <p class="help-block error" id="error-current-password">This is where the error should be.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field animated-label text required">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" aria-required="true" autocomplete="on" style="max-height: 67px; padding-top: 27px;" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="error-email">
        <div class="error-block" style="display: none;">
          <p class="help-block error" id="error-email">This is where the error should be.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this works, but so did my implementation. The question being how to get this work on all the input elements. I have a `for` loop developed but the logic needs to be refactored and thats where I am getting stuck on.

Comment: without a `for` loop? I asked because I tried your implementation and it still only works on the first input element.

Comment: Exactly..........

Comment: yours only works on the first input element just like in my environment. The idea is if the user clicks inside any of the input elements and then clicks out, it generates the error block for that particular element. Right now yours is the same as what I have, where only the first input element has this behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220374/discussion-between-daniel-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I added handling of the nearest error block. It will work for all "INPUT" currently

Comment: yes that works.

Comment: So it works in Codepen but not my project, or rather it only half works in my project.

Comment: I can only help if you show the code. Any console errors?

Comment: it works in Firefox but its not working in Chrome, any ideas?

Comment: That is not very helpful. Any console errors?